Round Table and Diners
Around a round table sit two males and three females, each differing significantly in age. Each person eats one type of food, drinks one type of beverage, and uses one type of seasoning. All food, beverages, and seasonings are unique to each individual. The following clues are provided:

The person drinking juice uses chili sauce.

The person drinking soda is a teenage girl.

The middle-aged individual and the young adult are separated by someone eating fried rice.

The person using soy sauce and the person drinking milk are separated by someone eating French fries.

The person drinking beer sits next to someone eating bread, and these two are of the same gender. The former has a kid sitting on his/her other side.

The person using pepper sits next to someone eating sushi, and these two are of opposite genders. The former has an elderly individual sitting on his/her other side.

The person drinking tea, the person eating noodles, and the person using vinegar are one male and one female.


A person uses sugar. How old is this person?
